# Bootstrap Select Display Bug

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Silvio Moreto's BootStrap library](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) and it's not displaying the select properly.

Here is a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWzm7.jpg) of the problem.

My guess is I am doing something wrong. I don't know what's causing this issue, but I checked 
my javascript load order and that seems fine.

Below is the html I execute the code on.

```
<select name="action_type" class='selectpicker'>
  <option value="phone">call</option>
  <option value="email">email</option>
  <option value="url">open to url</option>
</select>
```

This is the expanded form after selectpicker() is executed.

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select">
  <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <div class="filter-option pull-left">call</div>&nbsp;
    <div class="caret"></div></button><div class="dropdown-menu open">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu">
      <li rel="0" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" style=""><span class="text">call</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
      <li rel="1"><a tabindex="0" class="" style=""><span class="text">email</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
      <li rel="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" style=""><span class="text">open to url</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on? I presume it could be the CSS.

Update::

I only use certain parts of the bootstrap framework because there's a lot that I don't need. I use version 2.3.2 of button, form, and dropdown js/css, but, for some reason, it isn't enough for bootstrap selector.

Here is a picture using only bootstrap 3.0 sources from the [test file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8j6M.jpg).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of your complete HTML? Do you load the javascript as well as the css?

Comment: Yes, I load both. I believe its dependencies are bootstrap dropdown js and css.

Comment: I don't use the whole twitter bootstrap framework and only download what I need. So far, I only use button.js/css form.js/css and dropdown.js. I also included bootstrap-select.js/css

Comment: I will try using the files that came in the test file and report back

Comment: Avoid calling things bugs... It insinuates and error in the library when it may be a fault with your code / usage.

Comment: Good point! I will keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the jQuery libray and told it which elements to apply the changes to?

From the libraries docs...

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

You will need to do this on document.ready

Comment: Yes, I do this in my backbone view. Thanks!